# Grab the current position of a moving ellipse in processing.js

Tags: java, game-physics, 2d-games

Easy Question! I have an ellipse moving from left to right, I was wondering if there is anyway to store a specific point in that left to right path in a variable

e.g when the ellipse hits position X 100 pixels, store the specific position of the ellipse in a variable.

I'd like the ellipse must continue to run from left.

```
void draw(){     

    background(44,209,216); 

    fill(colourR,250,182);     
    noStroke();    
    ellipse(posX,posY,100,50);          

    posX = posX + speed;

    if(posX == 100){
        store posX in a variable
    }                  
}
```

That is the sort of process I am looking for, the problem I am getting is that when I try to do something like `newPosX = posX`, they both continue to increment. How can I make it so `newPosX` stores the current position of `posX` and `posX` continues to increment? Also I mean that `newPosX` can NOT just `= 100`, I want to grab the position of `posX` when it hits 100 and store it in a variable.

Comment: When posX hits 100 it will always contain 100! or why you do not just store value 100 within some constant variable?

Comment: Can you please include the full code? Also, is this Processing or Processing.js?

Comment: Please post more of your code, because if you are doing what you plead it should be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I made this sample to show you, here i'm giving newPosX the value of posX just as you want, if you test it you'll see the value of newPosX remains while the value of posX keeps changing. Perhaps the problem it's in your declaration of variables.

```
  int posX, newPosX;

    void setup(){
      size(200,100);
      posX = 0;
      newPosX = 0;
    }

    void draw(){     

        background(44,209,216);    

        posX = mouseX;

        if(posX == 100){
           newPosX = posX;
        }              

        println(posX + " PosX");
        println(newPosX + " newPosX");

    }
```

Regards Jose.